# Create new folder for uploaded files - Razor Engine

Tags: asp.net, razor, asp.net-webpages

I was checking this tutorial on

http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/files,-images,-and-media/working-with-files

On this topic i saw that is possible to send various files to a destination folder.

My question is, how can i make a new directory when the user sends a file or more files?

```
@using Microsoft.Web.Helpers;
@{
  var message = "";
  if (IsPost) {
  var fileName = "";
  var fileSavePath = "";
  int numFiles = Request.Files.Count;
  int uploadedCount = 0;
  for(int i =0; i < numFiles; i++) {
      var uploadedFile = Request.Files[i];
      if (uploadedFile.ContentLength > 0) {
          fileName = Path.GetFileName(uploadedFile.FileName);
          fileSavePath = Server.MapPath("~/uploadedFiles/" + fileName);
          uploadedFile.SaveAs(fileSavePath);
          uploadedCount++;
      }
   }
   message = "File upload complete. Total files uploaded: " + uploadedCount.ToString();
   }
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>FileUpload - Multiple File Example</title></head>
<body>
<form id="myForm" method="post"
   enctype="multipart/form-data"
   action="">
<div>
<h1>File Upload - Multiple-File Example</h1>
@if (!IsPost) {
    @FileUpload.GetHtml(
        initialNumberOfFiles:2,
        allowMoreFilesToBeAdded:true,
        includeFormTag:true,
        addText:"Add another file",
        uploadText:"Upload")
    }
<span>@message</span>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just before saving the file, create the folder that you want. [`Directory.CreateDirectory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/54a0at6s.aspx) will automatically create your folder and any other non existing folders in the specified path. After creating your target folder, just save the file to that location.

```
if (uploadedFile.ContentLength > 0) {
      fileName = Path.GetFileName(uploadedFile.FileName);

      string pathToSave = Server.MapPath("~/") + "/uploadedFiles/" + yourCustomFolderName;
      Directory.CreateDirectory(pathToSave);

      fileSavePath = pathToSave + fileName;

      uploadedFile.SaveAs(fileSavePath);
      uploadedCount++;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Andrei V,

I tried to copy your code to teste and got the following errors:

Compiler Error Message: CS1026: ) expected

Source Error:

Compiler Error Message: CS1026: ) expected

Source Error:


Line 13:       fileName = Path.GetFileName(uploadedFile.FileName);
Line 14: 
Line 15:       string pathToSave = Server.MapPath("~/uploadedFiles/" + yourCustomFolderName
Line 16:       Directory.CreateDirectory(pathToSave);
Line 17:

Comment: @Nibbler, I forgot to close the parenthesis. Please check now. If you still get an error, post it's content too, not just the line where it happens.

Comment: Compiler Error Message: CS1002: ; expected

Line 15:       string pathToSave = Server.MapPath("~/") + "/uploadedFiles/" + yourCustomFolderName

Comment: Updated. Please note that you need to declare a variable `yourCustomFolderName` which holds the name of the (sub)folder you wish to save in or a hardcoded value such as "dataFiles".

Comment: Already declared but now i got the same error above on line 18.

Compiler Error Message: CS1002: ; expected
Line 18:       fileSavePath = pathToSave + fileName);

Comment: Updated. These where editing errors. You should have picked on that. Anyway, sorry about that.

Comment: You don't need to apologize. I'm new to this. Thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: Gladly. Practice some more :)

Comment: Sorry to bother you again @Andrei V I tested and it's ok it creates the folder, but the file that is uploaded doesn't go inside the folder that was created. It's possible to do that ?

Comment: Sure it's possible. First, check (& debug) some things though: check if the `fileSavePath` is generated as you originally wanted (i.e. it's a proper file address) and if you have "write" permission on that folder (it shouldn't be the case, since you created it, but...).

Comment: Ok so after some tries and some research i come to this:

uploadedFile.SaveAs(Path.Combine(pathToSave,fileName));

and it works fine.

Again thanks for your guidance